# How to find and extract certain string from XML and replace in another XML document

Tags: python, xml, batch-file, automation

can someone help me on how to extract certain string from xml and replace in another xml. Like I want to extract only mediaId from second line of 1.XML

```
- <sample_settings_config version="23" mediaId="0x6868">
```

and replace it in 2.xml document (code of both XML's are same except the mediaId).

Where as 1.xml location is dynamic (C:\users\xxxx\Documents), so am looking for append, find extract and replace. :(

I am trying for Python or batch script.

struggling with this batch script

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(Set UPD=C:\Users)

(Set UDS=\RAP\Documents\MB)

For /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I /L "mediaId" 1.xml') do (
   set "line=%%a"
   set "line=!line:*<string>=!"
   for /F "delims=<" %%b in ("!line!") do echo %%b
```

but it is not working, any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: if `(code of both XML's are same except the mediaId)` as you say, then if you extract the `mediaId` value from 1.xml and replace it in the corresponding line in 2.xml, then 2.xml will be the same as 1.xml. Need more information about exactly what is going on - some examples would be useful.

Comment: Based upon what you've wrote in your question, if the code of both XML's are same except the `mediaId`, in `2.xml`, and you want the one in `1.XML` to be transferred over, then you just need to `Copy  /Y "1.XML" "2.xml"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree()

tree.parse("1.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
media_id = root.find('sample_settings_config').attrib['mediaId']

tree.parse("2.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
root.find('sample_settings_config').attrib['mediaId'] = media_id
tree.write('2.xml', xml_declaration=True)
```

You can use `xml.etree.ElementTree` to read and
write to XML, by the use of Python.

The code imports `ElementTree` and an instance is
created as `tree`. From `tree`, the XML file is
parsed and get the `root`. Then, find the tag
`sample_settings_config` and get the value of the
attribute of `mediaId`.

Repeat the parsing, get `root` and find the tag.
Update the dictionary key of `mediaId` with the
value stored in the variable `media_id`.
Write the modified content to the XML file.

**1.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>
<root>
  <sample_settings_config version="123" mediaId="0x6868">
    "XML File 1"
  </sample_settings_config>
</root>
```

**2.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>
<root>
  <sample_settings_config version="456" mediaId="0x0">
    "XML File 2"
  </sample_settings_config>
</root>
```

**2.xml modified**:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>
<root>
  <sample_settings_config mediaId="0x6868" version="456">
    "XML File 2"
  </sample_settings_config>
</root>
```